# How can I label my sub-processes for logging when using multicore and doMC in R

Tags: r, logging, multicore, domc

I have started using the `doMC` package for R as the parallel backend for parallelised `plyr` routines.

The parallelisation itself seems to be working fine (though I have yet to properly benchmark the speedup), my problem is that the logging is now asynchronous and messages from different cores are getting mixed in together. I could created different logfiles for each core, but I think I neater solution is to simply add a different label for each core. I am currently using the `log4r` package for my logging needs.

I remember when using MPI that each processor got a rank, which was a way of distinguishing each process from one another, so is there a way to do this with `doMC`? I did have the idea of extracting the PID, but this does seem messy and will change for every iteration.

I am open to ideas though, so any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT (2011-04-08):** Going with the suggestion of one answer, I still have the issue of correctly identifying which subprocess I am currently inside, as I would either need separate closures for each `log()` call so that it writes to the correct file, or I would have a single `log()` function, but have some logic inside it determining which logfile to append to. In either case, I would still need some way of labelling the current subprocess, but I am not sure how to do this.

Is there an equivalent of the `mpi_rank()` function in the MPI library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think having multiple process write to the same file is a recipe for a disaster (it's just a log though, so maybe "disaster" is a bit strong).

Often times I parallelize work over chromosomes. Here is an example of what I'd do (I've mostly been using foreach/doMC):

```
foreach(chr=chromosomes, ...) %dopar% {
  cat("+++", chr, "+++\n")
  ## ... some undoubtedly amazing code would then follow ...
}
```

And it wouldn't be unusual to get output that tramples over each other ... something *like* (not exactly) this:

```
+++chr1+++
+++chr2+++
++++chr3++chr4+++
```

... you get the idea ...

If I were in your shoes, I think I'd split the logs for each process and set their respective filenames to be unique with respect to something happening in that process's loop (like `chr` in my case above). Collate them later if you must ... ie. map/reduce your log files :-)